# LuaTeX hpack_filter callback not triggering on certain hlist creations

Tags: luatex, callback

**EDIT: The hpack_filter is triggered and my question pointless. Consult my answer on why I missed the callback invocation.**

I am using LuaTeX to analyze the creation process of math expressions in a document. To this effect, I use the `mlist_to_hlist` callback to insert a `whatsit` node into the node list. When the math expressions are assembled into their final form by packing various node lists into horizontal and vertical lists, I hook into this process with `hpack_filter` and `vpack_filter` callbacks. This allows me to follow the creation path from the raw math expression all the way to the final page.

I encounter an issue with a specific part of this process. It seems that the rows of an `align`-math-environment, are added to the main vertical list as horizontal lists with a specific subtype. These `hlist` nodes have subtype 4, which is described as 'alignment column or row' in the LuaTeX documentation.

My problem now is that the creation of exactly these `hlist`s is not filtered with the `hpack_filter` callback. For all other `hlist` types I get the expected invocation of `hpack_filter` but not for these. For my purposes, it already suffices to check the input arguments of this process for the occurrence of certain `whatsit` node and then completely cancel the packing. The goal is to not have this content transferred to the main vertical list.

This leads to my **questions**:

- Why is `hpack_filter` not called for the creation of an `hlist` with subtype 4?
- Is it possible to enable such a behavior or to somehow obtain an equivalent callback mechanism by other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While inspecting the node list that were given as arguments to the `hpack_filter` callbacks, I did not notice that the input argument contained `unset` nodes. My take on how an alignment (that is generated by the TeX command `\halign`) is treated by LuaTeX is as follows:

1. Through a series of `hpack` invocation with argument `groupcode == align_set`, the input node lists are packed into the `head` field of `unset` nodes.
2. These `unset` nodes (with `glue` nodes and perhaps other stuff) are then packed into an `hlist` node with subtype 4. The node lists that resided in the `head` fields of the `unset` nodes are still present but now in `head` fields of `hlist` nodes with subtype 5. This packing happens in an `hpack` invocation with argument `groupcode == fin_row`. **This exactly the part that I missed and that I was asking for.**

This is what I figured out by looking at intermediate node lists and is my own opinion. This information cannot be found in LuaTeX manual so far (version 0.76) and `unset` nodes are hardly mentioned at all. That they have a `head` field I deduced from looking at the LuaTeX source code.